# VBnet Edit/Delete Buttons not presented in table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Hey I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I'm quite new and struggling!

/////
THE PROBLEM I'M HAVING

I have created a table and would like to add the link 'Edit' 'Delete' next to it so I can change the criteria within in however the button has entirely disappeared.

Here is what I have in Visual Studio:

[image: I've added a photo of what I mean here]
It would be helpful if there's any certain requirements needed to enable this. Thanks.

Comment: You see that pane on the right? Does changing the values of AutoGenerateDeleteButton and AutoGenerateEditButton help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!!! @AndrewMorton